# Check if the data inserted correctly

Tags: mysql, pdo, locking, verify

I'm trying to get the inserted data from  the last multi insert query so I can verify the written data.
I use pdo to execute the query.

```
$sql="insert into tableName (col1,col2) values (val1,val2),(val4,val5),(val7,val8) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=VALUES(Col1),Col2=VALUES(Col2)";
$stmt = dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
```

and then I run the `lastInsertId()` to get the last id of my autoIncrement column.

```
$lastId=$dbh->lastInsertId();
```

and the rowCount() function to get the number of inserted rows (don't care about the duplicates)

```
$numberOfNewRows=$dbh->rowCount();
```

now I want to get the data from the previous insert query

```
$limitRangeStart=$lastId-$numberOfNewRows;


    $sql="select * from previusTable limit $limitRangeStart ,  $lastId ";
 $stmt = dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
```

So my question is will the last query ALWAYS return the data the previously query inserted since multi insert method used? 
Is there any possibility that another insert query that might run at that time will "break" the multi insert rows from the previous query?

Comment: if you already have an id get rid of the limit and simply use that to retrieve the data.. easy peasy. wont matter how many queries were ran in between if using the id..